# Regularization theorem :$ AC[0,1]$ to $\mathcal{C}^1[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-transform, regularization, absolute-continuity

For a given absolutely continuous function $x\in AC([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$ i.e : there is $f\in L^1[0,1]$ such that : $$x(t)= x(0)+ \int_0^tf(s)ds.$$
Can I find a continuously differentiable $y$, such that $y=x$ almost everywhere.

I was wondering if there is a regularization theorem.

Comment: If $x,y$ are continous and equal almost everywhere, they are equal everywhere. So no, this idea is not working.